# Full ASP.NET-style AppDomain assembly isolation

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm writing a plugin architecture for an automation scheduler which needs to be robust, so I'm attempting to do ASP.NET/IIS-style AppDomains -- i.e. each AppDomain is really treated as its own distinct application with no shared objects between them.

I'm setting `ApplicationBase`, `ConfigurationFile`, and `ShadowCopyFiles` in the `AppDomainSetup`.

There's one common assembly in the automation scheduler that I load for each plugin -- it handles loading up the plugin's main assembly, catching uncaught exceptions, and logging. There are a few weaknesses to this approach that I've identified:

- By setting `ApplicationBase` to where the plugin is stored, any dependencies of the common assembly (which resides in a different path) will no longer be resolved. I sort of hacked this into working by hooking the `AssemblyResolve` event, but that leads to other problems.
- It's possible that both the common assembly and the plugin reference their own copies of an identically named assembly -- possibly each having a different version. Or maybe an assembly with the same name but completely different contents. Overriding `AssemblyResolve`, the plugin's copy will always be loaded first.
- Not really worried about this one but from a security standpoint I recognize that it's possible for a plugin to override a dependency of the scheduler causing it to do something nefarious, or to reflect into the common assembly and get at internals.

So I've decided that perhaps the only way to do this properly is to simply not do it -- force a clean separation and not load any assemblies into the AppDomain. I'm not really sure what the best way to go about this is, or even if it's the best approach.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly answers your question, but we had a similar setup with an application where we had independent child AppDomains and a folder of shared DLLs, and we had success without using AssemblyResolve.

Our file structure was:

```
[PathToApplication]\OurApplication.exe
[PathToApplication]\AddIns\[SharedAssemblies]\*.dll
[PathToApplication]\AddIns\[FirstAddIn]\*.dll
[PathToApplication]\AddIns\[SecondAddIn]\*.dll
```

Where the parts in square brackets are replaced by the actual paths.

In our case the shared assemblies where also loaded by the main AppDomain, so we set that up in the main `App.config` as follows.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="AddIns\[SharedAssemblies]" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Make sure the shared assemblies don't exist alongside the main executable or it will load them from there instead, and that silently will stop the DLLs being shared in memory between all the AppDomains.

Then for each add-in's AppDomain we configured it so the base path was a folder above both the add-in's folder and the shared folder, and set the private bin paths up so it searched the correct sub-folders in the correct order:

```
var basePath = @"[PathToApplication]\AddIns";

var configFile = Path.Combine(
        basePath, 
        addInFolder, 
        addInAssemblyName + ".dll.config");

var binPaths = new [] { "[SharedAssemblyFolder]", addInFolder };

setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    ApplicationBase = basePath,
    ConfigurationFile = configFile,
    LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain,
    PrivateBinPath = string.Join(";", binPaths),
    PrivateBinPathProbe = string.Empty,
};
```

This way it always searches the shared folder first, so even if the add-in provides its own DLL with the same name it will be ignored.

We run this with `[System.LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain)]` set on the application entry point and have verified the DLLs are actually shared in memory (it's easy to get it slightly wrong and silently stop this happening).

Hope this helps in some way.